# Filtrant inductive limits commuting with global section functor

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Is it true that if $X$ is a compact space and $\{F_i\}_{i \in I}$ an inductive system of sheaves of $k$-modules on $X$, then the functor of global sections commutes with colimits?

I mean, I am asking if it is true that in such hypotheses

> $$ \varinjlim \Gamma(X; F_i) \simeq \Gamma(X; \varinjlim F_i)$$

I know that filtrant inductive limits are exact, i.e. commute with finite limits and colimits.

Also, I can write $\varinjlim \Gamma(X; F_i)  = \varinjlim \Gamma(X; \text{for}(F_i))  $, where "for" stands for the forgetful functor.
But I can't still move the colimit inside $\Gamma (X; -)$ (can do only if it was finite).
Then I think I should use compactness hypothesis but I am a bit confused because on one hand I need some finiteness condition on the index category $I$, on the other I have finiteness condition on open coverings of the topological space.

How to continue?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Quasi-compactness of $X$ only gives injectivity of the canonical map
$$\varinjlim_i \Gamma(X,F_i) \to \Gamma(X,\varinjlim_i F_i).$$
It is bijective if the transition maps $F_i \to F_j$ are injective. Another  sufficient condition for bijectivity is the following: Every open covering of $X$ has a refinement of the form $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ where $I$ is finite and the intersections $U_i \cap U_j$ are quasi-compact. A reference is [Stacks Project, Tag 0738](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0738). If you do not know what a site is, just replace it there by "topological space". An important example where the assumption applies is that of a quasi-compact quasi-separated scheme.